# Compatability error Installing Sharepoint w/ SP1 on Windows 2008 R2 RC

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint

I am trying to install sharepoint 2007 enterprise with SP1 on Windows Server 2008 R2 RC 64 bit.

I am getting a compatibility error.  Here is the text:

**[Window Title]
Program Compatibility Assistant**

**[Main Instruction]
This program is blocked due to compatibility issues**

**[Expanded Information]
You must install Office SharePoint Server 2007 - Please read Microsoft Knowledge Base article: 962935 with the most recent service pack. Office SharePoint Server 2007 - Please read Microsoft Knowledge Base article: 962935 without service packs has a known compatibility issue with this version of Windows.**

I can't find this KB article.  I have the most recent SP installer available with my MSDN subscription.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to install it with a [slipstreamed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slipstream_(computing)) copy of SP2 which has just been [released](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2009/04/28/announcing-service-pack-2-for-office-sharepoint-server-2007-and-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0.aspx) & provides support for R2:

> Q: Will Windows Server 2008 SP2 and WIndows Server 2008 R2 be supported?
>    A: Yes, they will be supported on their release

If you are just using WSS there is a link in the [blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2009/04/28/announcing-service-pack-2-for-office-sharepoint-server-2007-and-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0.aspx) for a donwload for Slipstreamed builds. If you are using MOSS you will need to create the slipstream yourself because:

> Q: Will there be a MOSS slipstream build?
>    A: So far there is no plan to create a MOSS slipstream build. Customers can refer to the slipstream guide on TechNet mentioned earlier in the blog to create their own build based on their needs.

A Microsoft guide to create the slipstream for MOSS is [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261890.aspx).

Another guide on making a slipstream image/install is [here](http://www.keirgordon.com/post/Installing-SharePoint-on-Windows-Server-2008-R2.aspx).

Edit: Added more details about slipstreaming and MOSS/WSS versions.

Comment: slipstreaming is the key here.

Comment: I have no idea what slipstreaming is, but there are some slipstream builds posted on that first link in this answer...  Can I just use those?

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slipstream_(computing) for info on slipstreaming. If you want to install WSS then you can use the link on the Microsoft blog. If you want to install MOSS you will have to make a slipstream because "So far there is no plan to create a MOSS slipstream build."
MS also has a guide on slipstreraming MOSS http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261890.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is quite late for you, but I came across this question when I had the same problem myself and wrote [this blog](http://www.dmcinfo.com/blog.aspx/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/180/Installing-Search-Server-Express-Over-Windows-Sharepoint-Services-30-with-Slipstream.aspx) as a step by step instruction on how to slipstream install Search Server Express.

Answer (score 0):

MOSS has a Service Pack 2 now - that's probably what it's talking about.

Answer (score 0):

http://keirgordon.com/post/Installing-SharePoint-on-Windows-Server-2008-R2.aspx

and

thecommunicator.co.cc/2009/12/18/windows-2008-r2-server-sharepoint-2007-kb962935-2/

article talks about the problem...

summary:

The steps for making a slipstreamed installation of MOSS are pretty simple.

```
* Download a MOSS image, and extract it (or copy the contents) to a folder.
* Download WSS and MOSS SP2 patches
* Run each patch with /extract:<c:\mymossimage>\Updates
* Delete Wsssetup.dll from the updates folder.
```

Keep in mind that if you have the combined x86/64 MOSS ISO, your updates folder will be in \x64\Updates or \x86\Updates.