# Installing TFS 2010 beta on Windows Server 2008 R2 RC

Tags: windows-server-2008, team-foundation-server

I am trying to get an install of the new TFS 2010 beta so I can demo it to my co-workers (on Tuesday).

I am not really a systems person, so I did not know that Windows Server 2008 R2 is a Release Candidate only.  I thought it was the current version.

I have it installed on a VM and have SQL Server 2008 Installed.  I am working on Sharepoint now and I am realizing that a lot of the software out there needs special versions to work with the Windows Server 2008 R2 RC.

So, my question is: Am I better off starting over with Windows Server 2008 or pressing on with Windows Server 2008 R2 RC?

Will TFS 2010 even run on Windows 2008 R2 RC?

Thanks for any responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guide really shows the step by step process to installing TFS 2010 on Windows Server 2008 R2:

http://blogs.msdn.com/dstfs/archive/2009/05/15/installing-tfs-2010-on-windows-server-2008-r2-rc.aspx

Answer (score 1):

> "...a lot of the software out there needs special versions to work with the Windows Server 2008 R2 RC..."

Are you coming up against the 32-bit vs. 64-bit issue? Do you need the large memory (3.5-4GB) support of the 64-bit OS?

If your 32-bit software won't run on R2 you may need to start over, with a 32-bit Windows Server 2008 VM, as R2 is the first OS only available as 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting this error?

> [Window Title] Program Compatibility Assistant
>
> [Main Instruction] This program is blocked due to compatibility issues
>
> [Expanded Information] You must install Office SharePoint Server 2007 - Please read Microsoft Knowledge Base article: 962935 with the most recent service pack. Office SharePoint Server 2007 - Please read Microsoft Knowledge Base article: 962935 without service packs has a known compatibility issue with this version of Windows.

This question is asked [elsewhere](https://serverfault.com/questions/11103/compatability-error-installing-sharepoint-w-sp1-on-windows-2008-r2-rc), and the article KB962935 seems to be missing. If you have this error then it may be better to start over with a supported server version. There's a workaround ([How to install MOSS 2007 SP2 on Windows 7 RC (build 7100)](http://msdnrss.thecoderblogs.com/2009/05/08/how-to-install-moss-2007-sp2-on-windows-7-rc-build-7100/)) that sounds like too much work for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the help nray.  I decided to push through and see if I can get it to work.  FYI that question was asked by me :)